# Can not import from 'sockjs-client' (typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, sockjs

I am very new to angular and typescript.

First I install via npm:

```
npm install --save sockjs-client
```

I am trying to import like this in chat.component.ts:

```
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
```

But I am getting this error:

> TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'sockjs-client'.
> '/home/simon/javaprojs/tour-creator/client/node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/entry.js'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/sockjs-client` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts)
> file containing `declare module 'sockjs-client';`

So after that I tried the following as suggested by the error:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/sockjs-client
```

But that only resulted in a new warning:

> Warning:
> /home/simon/javaprojs/tour-creator/client/src/app/components/chat/chat.component.ts
> depends on 'sockjs-client'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause
> optimization bailouts. For more info see:
> https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Here is the full code of my component

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import * as Stomp from 'stompjs';
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.css'],
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  connect(): void {
    const socket = new SockJS('gs-guide-websocket');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.connect();
  }
}
```

What to do? When I start the application, all I get is a white page, and a console error saying that global is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is 'best practice' but it works for me.

In the index.html file I simply load SockJS via  tag.

And then in top of my chat.component.ts I add the following:

```
declare var SockJS: any;
```

Answer (score 3):

Please execute below commands and try again.

```
npm install --save sockjs-client    
npm install --save @types/sockjs-client

npm audit fix
```

Please add this declaration

```
declare module 'sockjs-client';
```

You can also visit this link:
[How to add SockJS into Angular 2 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278853/how-to-add-sockjs-into-angular-2-project)

Comment: I'll try it later today, thanks for your answer

Comment: Please first uninstall  @types/sockjs-client. It worked for me today

Comment: This did not fix my issue. I still get this warning on build:
Warning: /home/simon/javaprojs/tour-creator/client/src/app/components/chat/chat.component.ts depends on 'sockjs-client'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Application starts up with a blank page and a console error

Comment: But I worked for me. Let's try to dig dipper. Will let you know if I can find anything.

Comment: I tried deleting my node_modules folder, and doing the 3 steps you suggested. But no luck

Answer (score 0):

actually, in order to benefit of typings you need to import the default value:

```
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
```